# IE reversing Arabic charterers automatically

Tags: html, internet-explorer, arabic, right-to-left

I am currently using Arabic language to display message on Internet Explorer. Web browser is reversing Arabic character automatically I believe which is correct behavior but I don’t want browser should automatically reverse my Arabic characters. 
Do you have any idea which setting will help me to disable automatic reversing by browser?

For example:

HTML page source code:

```
<html lang="ar" dir="ltr">
    <body>
        <p>
            &#1570;
        </p>
        <p>
            &#1581;
        </p>
        <div>
            &#1570;&#1581;
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Actual output:

آ

ح

آح

Expected output:

آ

ح

ح آ

Comment: Don't use `lang="ar"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed the correct behaviour - in a predominantly left-to-right context runs of Arabic characters should be rendered right-to-left, with the whole run then placed at the appropriate point in the main left-to-right flow.  But there are additional non-printing control characters you can insert into the text to override the default bidirectional rendering behaviour.

Placing the "left to right override" character (`&#x202d;`) before the Arabic text will force the renderer to display the characters from left to right instead of right to left.  You should also add a `&#x202c;` ("pop directional formatting") after the run to restore the normal rendering behaviour for following text.

```
&#x202d;&#1570;&#1581;&#x202c;
```

renders as

> ‭آح‬

You get the same result by inserting the Arabic characters in reverse order:

```
&#1581;&#1570;
```

renders as

> حآ

(I don't speak Arabic so I don't know which of these two orderings is the correct *logical* order - the way the Unicode rendering algorithms work you're supposed to provide characters in the stream in their logical order regardless of the reading direction of a particular language)